# Send woocommerce checkout data to another table in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to send the values in the checkout form to my custom table in wordpress after customer clicks on the place order button. As i understood that happens through the woocommerce_checkout_order_review function. But i want to know how to do this in a proper way.
Can please anybody suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add an action to woocommerce_checkout_process.

an example would be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'send_data_to_another_table');

function send_data_to_another_table() {
    //Your Code Here
}
```

Within the function you will need to insert the data in to your wordpress table.

Comment: yes i understand that i can use this hook with this function. But what i exactly want is after all the fields validated those values should go to my table. But in the woocommerce/plugin/template folder i can't find where this function is located.

Comment: you could just to an insert into db on the thankyou page. This will then only post once the checkout process has been complete and all fields are validated.

Comment: Thank you danyo for your instructions. But can you tell me whether the data that i take at the thank you page are all validated?

Comment: If you were to post the data from the checkout page to the thank you page, and have validation on the fields within the checkout form, then yes.

Comment: I tried the above code and put them in class-wc-checkout.php.but it did not work.Can anybody suggest me another way.

Comment: the file you will need to insert the above in is /templates/checkout/thankyou.php